# Swift: Trying to display weekdays from date string at indexPath.row

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm getting dates in string format and I would like to display weekdays for each dates for each row.
This is the code I have so far:

```
//{ConvertDate = "05/04/2015";},{ConvertDate = "05/05/2015";},{ConvertDate = "05/06/2015";},{ConvertDate = "05/07/2015";} etc...

let rowData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as! NSDictionary

//convert json date string to nsdate
var dateString = rowData["ConvertDate"] as? String
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy"
var dateFromString = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString!)

//convert string into weekday
var formatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEEE"
let stringDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())

//my labels        
cell.dateLabel.text = rowData["ConvertDate"] as? String
cell.dayLabel.text = stringDate
```

I'm getting the same weekday displayed for each row

Tuesday
05/04/2015

Tuesday
05/05/2015

Tuesday
05/06/2015

Tuesday
05/07/2015

How do I get the weekday to set based on string date for that row.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unrelated, but setting up an `NSDateFormatter` is expensive due to the locale information involved. It looks like you're doing it here in a table view function that will get called frequently—try making the `dateFormatter` a static property instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let stringDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(NSDate())
```

gives you the weekday from the *current day*. It probably should be

```
let stringDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(dateFromString)
```

to convert the date from the corresponding element from the data
source array.

Answer (score 3):

There's another way to do this that doesn't use a formatter to get the day name. You can index on your first `NSDateFormatter`'s weekday symbols array after getting the date's index:

```
let weekdayIndex = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().component(.CalendarUnitWeekday, fromDate: dateFromString!) - 1
let weekdayString = dateFormatter.weekdaySymbols[weekdayIndex]
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are always taking the week day from today `NSDate()`. Try:

```
let stringDate: String = formatter.stringFromDate(dateFromString!)
```

Hope this helps